# ¿Se puede contar los clicks realizados en un iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un `iframe` y me gustaría saber si de cualquier forma podría **contar los clicks** realizados dentro de este.

Y si no se puede, ¿Serviría un contador de clicks general? Es decir, un script que cuente los clicks realizados **aún que sea en toda la página, incluido el ifram**e.

Puedo usar JavaScript y cualquier librería.

Esto es lo que he probado, y parece ser que con `onclick` no sirve:

```
<div onclick="alert('Click');"><iframe src="https://es.stackoverflow.com"></iframe></div>
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que puedes llegar a hacer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var pulsaciones = 0;

    $("#iframe").on('click',function(){
    pulsaciones +=1;
  $("#contador").append(pulsaciones);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="iframe" style="border: solid 1px black;height:200px;width:200px;">
 </div>
 <div id="contador"></div>
```